# Populate Google Maps infowindow from a database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a problem with filling Google Maps infowindows from a database.
The concept i'm having is the following: A database filled with marker information such as the longitude and latitude, and another table which is filled with corresponding information.
I've managed to fill the map with the markers, however filling the infowindow with the correct information is something i'm struggeling with for 2 days already.

The code i'm using is the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
<?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","unwdmi");
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT stationNummer ,longitude, latitude FROM stations");

        $i = 0;

        $array = array();
        $array2 = array();
        $array3 = array();

        while ($heg = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $array[$i] = $heg['longitude'];
            $array1[$i] = $heg['latitude'];
            $array2[$i] = $heg['stationNummer'];

            $i++;
        }
        $i = 0;
?>
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src=
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1tbIAqN0XqcgTR1-          FxYoVTVq6Is6lD98&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var infos = [];
var locations = [ <?php
    foreach($array as $value) {
        $longitude = $value;
        $latitude = $array1[$i];
        $stationNummer = $array2[$i];


        $test = "'loan', $latitude, $longitude, 'address $i'"; ?> [ <?php echo $test; ?> ], <?php
        $i++;
    } ?>
];

$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php', //This is the current doc
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json', // add json datatype to get json
    data: ({
        stationNummer: 10015
    }),
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});

function initialize() {

    var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.890542, 151.274856),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("default"),
        myOptions);

    setMarkers(map, locations)

}


function setMarkers(map, locations) {

    var marker, i

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        var loan = locations[i][0]
        var lat = locations[i][1]
        var long = locations[i][2]
        var add = locations[i][3]

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php', //This is the current doc
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json', // add json datatype to get json
            data: ({
                loan
            }),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

        latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            title: loan,
            position: latlngset
        });
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())



        var content = data;

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content, infowindow) {
            return function() {

                /* close the previous info-window */
                closeInfos();

                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);

                /* keep the handle, in order to close it on next click event */
                infos[0] = infowindow;

            };
        })(marker, content, infowindow));

    }
}

function closeInfos() {

    if (infos.length > 0) {

        /* detach the info-window from the marker ... undocumented in the API docs */
        infos[0].set("marker", null);

        /* and close it */
        infos[0].close();

        /* blank the array */
        infos.length = 0;
    }
}
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="default" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
 </body>
  </html>

  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="default" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
 </body>
  </html>
```

The PHP file i'm reffering to is this:

```
<?php
  $userAnswer = $_POST['loan']; 
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","unwdmi");
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT temp, prcp, wdsp, cldc FROM measurement WHERE stationNummer =".$userAnswer."");
  while ($heg1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     $temp = $heg1['temp'];
     $prcp = $heg1['prcp'];
     $wdsp = $heg1['wdsp'];
     $cldc = $heg1['cldc'];
     }
   $text = "<table border='4'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Temperatuur</th>
                        <th>Neerslag</th>
                        <th>Windsnelheid</th>
                        <th>Bewolkingsgraad</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>".$temp."</td>
                        <td>".$prcp."</td>
                        <td>".$wdsp."</td>
                        <td>".$cldc."</td>
                    </tr>";
  echo json_encode($text);  
?>
```

I hope someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: You need to completely re-think your approach here.  You have 3 PHP arrays for all your data, the uselessly-named $array, $array1 and $array2, for longitudes, latitudes and station numbers.  Instead have one array which contains all those bits of data, eg `$stations[$i] = [
 'latitude' => $heg['latitude'],
 'longitude' => $heg['longitude'],
 'stationNummer' => $heg['stationNummer']
];`  And then that might make life slightly easier when you start trying to convert that to JS, for one thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't made any tests but I'm pretty sure you cannot use  in your javascript.

Imho the best way would be to create javascript variables (instead of php ones, cf. $longitude, ...) in the php then call them from your JS code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php 
        ...
        foreach($array as $value) {
            "var longitude = " . $value;
            ....
        } ?>
</script>
```

After this you should be able to use longitude in your js.

Tell me if I haven't be clear enough.